# Dynamically assign property of object with mixed-type properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object, properties, assign, mixed-type

Suppose I have an object with some properties that are not all the same type, and I want to assign a dynamic value to a dynamically identified property. This works perfectly fine in JavaScript, but how do I do it in TypeScript, eliminating the `not assignable to type 'never'` TS(2322) error, ideally without using `any`?

Sample code ([playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADYFtkG8BQyRyIcWKAXMgM5hSgDmA3IcQCYCuUcYwA9iACSIAMoQEAttWRUQHLACNoLAL74JIWsiwBPVBxAJeA5AF5kMA0f4gAFKyIxMWKumwAaBxecAFKHwAHaDAdADkyCCoAawgdPhg0Z09iEggAdwA1OAwOSJo6RmQAHxJ5JSh8AEo8LwwIMGQAN2zcs29sAG0nbD9A4LCIgF0WFI1qPjqAOgw+BlsAcgBRAA9gWkLmnMj59yaWiEqmZAB6Y83WteR45BCg5AADWnoQBmLSxWh73dAYaCgINjIUDIAL0PhQZAYUAQLynAAqAAseNoIHBNDckQ0TP84Gxdt0sF1fP4glAQuFyIMgdJrrcUI8Ci83nIPlB7sg4NIIMsgkYAZNYccABJ8NIQRrQXYmNL0SDfMDzGkJOkPEDi6CTe5eAlEnok-oUiBU8xqzL7I6nEB8Bqc6jABikBR1G58G46O7zNUSqDzSZgai2ABMAGZA4HKl5zigTekslsLcc0uCotIAFYcLRONXINLAMAI5AKa0Fu1sCDSTkPJ6FEos8palKnADCCPEUUK+eRdOkWB4CBLEAgWGkUJiHJoEE0wCdKH+AEcOMB-uRwIWOA02HxyyB5g1WxgAhQvMAYLY6dcdQTeqTyUMzKZzOeEqa47lqgQUiko20X+aTonk2kLMYU-YhL2JPoyQGSkf1jP9TmoCJkD+cEOQrIsJS8NRG2OdUQGQfs2w7TFC2LDl-nHaheRPYAEHyNE2DgKBARVTdt13ZB90PY9TyfdpCSvfUoMNY0H2QRVGQYeZkAAMhkt0gmuX8tnvcwJOeKT3y8L99lgs143-JMoBTbw1W0sDnF1LBrwNO8Y303IE0Q8hkKgfwIUrOAMJA4g1BUIA)):

```js
interface Film {
    name : string;
    durationInSeconds : number;
}
const myFunction = function(
    film: Film,
    filmPropertyName: keyof Film,
    newValue: string | number
) {
    let value = film[filmPropertyName];
    console.log('Existing value:', value); //value is of type `string | number`, inferred in prior line
    //That means that on read, film[filmPropertyName] is of type `string | number` as expected.
    //However, on write, it's of type `never.`
    film[filmPropertyName] = newValue; //not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
    value = newValue; //works just fine with both sides as `string | number`
    //Checking that types match seems like a sensible requirement but doesn't help:
    if(typeof film[filmPropertyName] === typeof newValue) {
        value = newValue; //works fine
        film[filmPropertyName] = newValue; //same error as above
    }
    //even checking that both are a specific standard type doesn't help:
    if(typeof film[filmPropertyName] === 'string' && typeof newValue === 'string') {
        value = newValue; //works fine
        film[filmPropertyName] = newValue; //same error as above
    }
}
```

In this tiny example, one might propose removing the type mix e.g. by setting `durationInSeconds` to a `string` type and changing the type of the `newValue` param to `string` only.  While that might be OK in a tiny example like this, it doesn't work on more complex real code where other types are needed.

For someone else coming upon this question, changing the type of the `film` parameter to `any` satisfies this error, but may trigger others e.g. if `film` or its properties are passed on to other functions during the body of this one.

Casting before the assignment, e.g. `(film as any)[filmPropertyName] = newValue`, makes the error go away and should probably be done within at least the first typechecking conditional, but seems to be giving up the typechecking power of TypeScript - adding `any` annotations and casts really doesn't seem like "the TypeScript way." What is, in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a double-generic in the type signature like this, keeping everything else the same:

```
const myFunctionGeneric = function<K extends keyof Film, V extends Film[K]>(
    film: Film,
    filmPropertyName: K,
    newValue: V
)
```

Revised playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).